# SQL Group patients by age range and sex

Tags: sql, count, group-by, case

Table is patient.birthdate and patient.sex
I can't create a new table.

Hey All, my query is attempting to list patients by sex and age range. I have this currently.

```
SELECT CASE
     WHEN patient.birthdate  > '01-jan-1988'  THEN '1-25' 
     WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1963' THEN '25-50'
     WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1938' THEN '50-75' 
     ELSE '75+' 
   END AS Age_Range, 
   COUNT(patient.sex) AS "M",
   (SELECT COUNT(patient.sex) FROM patient WHERE patient.sex = 'F' ) AS "F" 
FROM patient
WHERE patient.sex = 'M'
GROUP BY CASE 
       WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1988'  THEN '1-25' 
       WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1963' THEN '25-50'
       WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1938' THEN '50-75'
       ELSE '75+' 
     END
     ORDER BY Age_Range;
```

And this is my output is correctly grouping and counting the males but for the females I get the same number for each age range (3538) which is the total number of female patients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE
  WHEN patient.birthdate  > '01-jan-1988'  THEN '1-25' 
  WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1963' THEN '25-50'
  WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1938' THEN '50-75' 
  ELSE '75+' 
END AS Age_Range, 
SUM(CASE WHEN patient.Sex = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Males,
SUM(CASE WHEN patient.Sex = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Females
FROM patient
GROUP BY CASE
  WHEN patient.birthdate  > '01-jan-1988'  THEN '1-25' 
  WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1963' THEN '25-50'
  WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1938' THEN '50-75' 
  ELSE '75+' 
END
```

Comment: Think you need an END keyword in your case statement. Otherwise it looks good.

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev you were missing the `END` in the `SUM(CASE..)`

Comment: Thanks, I've added the end and it works great! First time on stackoverflow and it was better than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE
     WHEN patient.birthdate  > '01-jan-1988'  THEN '1-25' 
     WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1963' THEN '25-50'
     WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1938' THEN '50-75' 
     ELSE '75+' 
   END AS Age_Range, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN patient.sex = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "M Count",  
   SUM(CASE WHEN patient.sex = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "F Count"
FROM patient
WHERE patient.sex = 'M'
GROUP BY CASE 
       WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1988' THEN '1-25' 
       WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1963' THEN '25-50'
       WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1938' THEN '50-75'
       ELSE '75+' 
     END
     ORDER BY Age_Range;
```

I would also suggest this (if your system supports CTE), I think it is clearer (and may be faster)

```
WITH NewAge AS
(
  SELECT CASE
       WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1988' THEN '1-25' 
       WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1963' THEN '25-50'
       WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1938' THEN '50-75' 
       ELSE '75+' 
     END AS Age_Range, 
     CASE WHEN patient.sex = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS "M",  
     CASE WHEN patient.sex = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS "F"  
  FROM patient
)
SELECT Age_Range, COUNT(M) AS "M Count", COUNT(F) AS "F Count"
FROM NewAge
GROUP Age_Range
ORDER BY Age_Range;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE`

```
SELECT CASE
     WHEN patient.birthdate  > '01-jan-1988'  THEN '1-25' 
     WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1963' THEN '25-50'
     WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1938' THEN '50-75' 
     ELSE '75+' 
     SUM(CASE WHEN patient.Sex = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS M,
     SUM(CASE WHEN patient.Sex = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS F
   END AS Age_Range, 
FROM patient
WHERE patient.sex = 'M'
GROUP BY CASE 
       WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1988'  THEN '1-25' 
       WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1963' THEN '25-50'
       WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1938' THEN '50-75'
       ELSE '75+' 
     END
     ORDER BY Age_Range;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE
     WHEN patient.birthdate  > '01-jan-1988'  THEN '1-25' 
     WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1963' THEN '25-50'
     WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1938' THEN '50-75' 
     ELSE '75+' 
   END AS Age_Range, 
   COUNT(CASE WHEN patient.sex = 'M' THEN patient.sex END) AS "M Count",  
   COUNT(CASE WHEN patient.sex = 'F' THEN patient.sex END) AS "F Count"
FROM patient
GROUP BY CASE 
       WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1988'  THEN '1-25' 
       WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1963' THEN '25-50'
       WHEN patient.birthdate > '01-jan-1938' THEN '50-75'
       ELSE '75+' 
     END
     ORDER BY Age_Range;
```